# Check for visibility of dynamic content with JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if the message:

```
"Nenhuma conversa ou mensagem foram encontradas"
```

is visible for the user in this site:

```
https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

With Javascript,
The message appears when I search for a string and the app doesn't find any results.

But I'm unable to do this.

This is my code unitl now:

```
function isHidden(el) {
    return (el.offsetParent === null)
}
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("empty-text");
isHidden(a);
```

But isHidden always returns false, even if I'm not seeing the message in the screen.

How can I correctly check for the visibility of the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works very well. This checks if the item is in view

```
function isvisible(el){
  return window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= el.offsetTop
}
window.onscroll=function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("isHidden");
  if(isvisible(elem)){
    //some code
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting js Error: DomUtil: elem is not an element. when I try this: var a = document.getElementsByClassName("empty-text");

Comment: Need a number at the end `...ty-text")[0]`